# Help with the creation of this special table

Tags: tables, tabularx, code

I will post down here the tableI need to create in LaTeX.

I actually have no clue with how to proceed. I only know basics tables codes.

Any help will be really appreciated!

P.s. I drew here a sample. I need actually more than three $\alpha$ cells and more than nine $t$ cells,but that won't be a problem of course: I will extend the code.

Thank you!!

[image]

About the size: I would like for the table to be quite large.

Not a landscape mode, but let's say $18$ cm in length. The height will depend upon how many $t$ and $\alpha$ I will put inside!

Comment: This is pretty straightforward with `multirow` and `\cline` etc. statements

Comment: Do you have 3 rows for `t = ` per each value of α?

Comment: @Bernard I will actually have $7$ rows for $t$, another $7$ or $8$ total rows for $\alpha$ !

Comment: I asked to know if the number of `t =` rows is even or add. In favourable cases (odd number) one can do  without using `\multirow`, which very often requires some manual vertical adjustment.

Comment: @Bernard Then I will have seven values for t, and7 for$\alpha$! Odd odd odd!

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\caption{Title here}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{9}{*}{$\sum_kf(k,\alpha,t)$} & \multirow{3}{*}{$\alpha=1$} & t=0.1 & 0.123456789   \\ \cline{3-4} 
                                       &                             & t=0.5 & 1.04400440    \\ \cline{3-4} 
                                       &                             & t=0.9 & 2.71828182845 \\ \cline{2-4} 
                                       & \multirow{3}{*}{$\alpha=2$} & t=0.1 &               \\ \cline{3-4} 
                                       &                             & t=0.5 &               \\ \cline{3-4} 
                                       &                             & t=0.9 &               \\ \cline{2-4} 
                                       & \multirow{3}{*}{$\alpha=3$} & t=0.1 &               \\ \cline{3-4} 
                                       &                             & t=0.5 &               \\ \cline{3-4} 
                                       &                             & t=0.9 &               \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

If you need a more readable version, consider using the `booktabs` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\caption{Title here}
\label{my-label2}
\begin{tabular}{ccl}
\toprule
 $\alpha$  & $t$   &  $\sum_kf(k,\alpha,t)$ \\ \midrule
 1         & 0.1   &  0.123456789           \\ 
           & 0.5   &  1.04400440            \\ 
           & 0.9   &  2.71828182845         \\ \midrule
 2         & 0.1   &                        \\  
           & 0.5   &                        \\  
           & 0.9   &                        \\ \midrule 
 3         & 0.1   &                        \\ 
           & 0.5   &                        \\  
           & 0.9   &                        \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is so cool! Thank you! Any way to make it larger?

Comment: Yes, of course, if you edit the question adding the exact size I can edit my answer

Comment: Done! I just need a length of about 18 cm. The height will depend on the total number son elements I'll put inside I guess. It would be awesome to have a clear well readable table! Thank you so much for what you wrote!

Comment: I just managed to learn about \resizebox and I'm don for what concerns the size! Thank you anyway! ^^

Comment: I'd avoid the `\multirow`: placing 1, 2 and 3 at the top implies the value stays the same for the empty cells underneath. Anyway, the “transpose” is what I'd use too.

Answer (score 5):

Taking partly into account an odd number of grouped rows, here a way, with `multirow, array, caption` and `siunitx` for the numbers alignment on the decimal dot in the last column.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow, array, caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
  \sisetup{table-format =1.11, table-number-alignment=center}
  \centering\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
  \caption{Title here}$ \begin{array}{|*{3}{c|}>{\color{red}}S|}%
  \hline
  \multirow{9}{*}{$ \sum_k f(k, \alpha, t) $}
  & & t = 0.1 & 0.123456789 \\
  \cline{3-4}  %
  &  \alpha= 1  & t = 0.5 & 1.04400440\\
  \cline{3-4}%
  &  & t = 0.9 & 2.71828182845 \\
  \cline{2-4}%
  & &t = 0.1 & 0.123456789\\ %
  \cline{3-4}%
  & \alpha=2  & t = 0.5 & 1.04400440\\
  \cline{3-4}%
  &  & t = 0.9 & 2.71828182845 \\
  \cline{2-4}%
  & &t = 0.1 &   \\
  \cline{3-4}%
  &  \alpha=3  & t = 0.5 &  \\
  \cline{3-4}%
  &  & t = 0.9 &  \\
  \hline%
  \end{array} $
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I assume it's important that the material in the first column be displayed in the blue and the material in the final column be displayed in red. I would also like to suggest you use an `array` environment since it looks like all contents should be rendered in math mode.

The following solution gets by without any `\multirow` directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % for '\extrarowheight' macro
\usepackage{xcolor}% for '\color' macro
\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % provide for a slightly more "open" look
\begin{array}{| >{\color{blue}}c | c | c | >{\color{red}}c |} \hline
                     &          & t=0.1 & 0.123545 \\ \cline{3-4}
                     & \alpha=1 & t=0.5 & 1.044044 \\ \cline{3-4}
                     &          & t=0.9 & 2.718281 \\ \cline{2-4}
                     &          & t=0.1 & \ldots   \\ \cline{3-4}
\sum_k f(k,\alpha,t) & \alpha=2 & t=0.5 & \ldots   \\ \cline{3-4}
                     &          & t=0.9 & \ldots   \\ \cline{2-4}
                     &          & t=0.1 & \ldots   \\ \cline{3-4}
                     & \alpha=3 & t=0.5 & \ldots   \\ \cline{3-4}
                     &          & t=0.9 & \ldots   \\ \hline
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```